# which is the best datepicker for birth date?

Tags: javascript

Which is the easiest to use/select date of birth?

Comment: I think you have to google something like "date picker javascript" you'll find alot!

Comment: First, that was rude, second, your question didn't say anything of the sort and quite obviously reads "I didn't try anything" whether you did or not. Post a better question next time if you don't want people to provide non-simplistic answers. Third, explain why specifically the standard date pickers of which there's a billion out there don't satisfy you.

Comment: Well, you didnt explain what you want exactly!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple text input and server side code (possibly duplicated on the client) that can parse various date formats and prompt the user to disambiguate entries such as 01/02/03.

Comment: Sounds about right. I'm also a proponent of the classic three-selects-side-by-side technique. +1

Comment: They can be fiddly, and are often implemented very poorly (i.e. given `Month: [----\/]` it isn't possible to tell (before you start to experiment) if you have to type `6`, `06` or `Ju` to skip down to June.)